# Why does wordpress redirect to some random article instead of showing a 404?

Tags: wordpress

I am testing 404's on my website and I'm expecting the path /a/b/c to show me a 404 because I haven't defined it: `localhost:8080/a/b/c`

However, it instead redirects to some article that, I assume, matches a/b/c in some form. My question is: where is that defined, and how do I turn it off? I've looked over htaccess, installed plugins, and in a few other places but I don't see where this is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add:

```
  add_filter('do_redirect_guess_404_permalink', '__return_false');
```